# Postgres: REGEXP_REPLACE using multiple columns

Tags: sql, regex, string, postgresql, select

I have a table like this:

```
Address                      | Remove1 | Remove2 | Remove3
-------------------------------------------------------------
100 Street, City, State Zip  | Street  |  City   | State
```

I want output like this:

```
Address                      | Remove1 | Remove2 | Remove3 | OutputCol
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
100 Street, City, State Zip  | Street  |  City   | State   | 100 *, *, * Zip
```

Basically I want to replace the text in Address Column matching on multiple remove columns with '*'

I have tried using `REGEXP_REPLACE` and `REPLACE` functions but both of them are giving partial results.
Is there a way I can use the `REGEXP_REPLACE(Address, (Remove1|Remove2|Remove3) , '*', 'g')` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you are quite close. You just need to properly concatenate the column values, like so:

```
regexp_replace(
    address,
    concat_ws('|', remove1, remove2, remove3),
    '*',
    'g'
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d57284403b98113efe03d9d4d5a531be)**:

```
select  
    t.*,
    regexp_replace(address, concat_ws('|', remove1, remove2, remove3), '*', 'g') OuputCol 
from mytable t
```

```
address                     | remove1 | remove2 | remove3 | ouputcol       
:-------------------------- | :------ | :------ | :------ | :--------------
100 Street, City, State Zip | Street  | City    | State   | 100 *, *, * Zip
```

Answer (score 1):

This is same as what you did. You just need string concatenation

```
with wt as 
(
   select '100 Street, City, State Zip' address, 
     'Street' Remove1, 'City' Remove2, 'State' Remove3
)
select REGEXP_REPLACE(address, '(' || Remove1 || '|' || Remove2 ||'|'||Remove3 ||')' , '*', 'g') from wt
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g35hqotAPiZU1nFTccLzkV/0)